# Code indentor using ANTLR 4

Tags: antlr, antlr4, pretty-print, auto-indent

I'am writing a code indentor using ANTLR4 and Java. I have successfully generated the lexer and the parser. And the approach i am using is to walk through the generated parse tree.

```
  ParseTreeWalker mywalker = new ParseTreeWalker();
  mywalker.walk(myListener, myTree);
```

The auto-generated *BaseListener has methods like below...

```
@Override public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
```

I'm very new to ANTLR. But, As I understand, I need to extend *BaseListener and override the relevant methods and write code to indent, So my question is what are the methods that I should be overriding for indenting the input code file? Or if there is an alternate approach I should take, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

None. You don't need a parser for this task and you are limiting yourself to valid code, when you require a parser (hence you cannot reformat code with a syntax error). Instead take the lexer and iterate over all tokens. Keep a state to know where you are (a block, a function, whatever) and indent according to that.